# Simple python format string test

Tags: python

I am having trouble to get the assignment done. Anyone gives a hint? Thanks a lot

http://www.learnpython.org/page/String%20Formatting

I have tried

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello"

print '%s %s %s %s ' %format_string % data
```

and it gives me not enough arguments for string error...

Comment: The expected output is mentioned on the page he linked to: `Hello John Doe. Your current balance is 53.44$.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to give you the full answer because this is a learning exercise. I'll only give you a hint.

Starting from here:

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello"
print format_string % data
```

The *only* line you need to change is the second line: `format_string = "....."`.

You need to change the contents of the string so that it contains three placeholders (`%s`), one for each value in `data`. You do not need to change the first or third lines.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the tuple can't be accessed like this. It should be accessed using the index values like `data[0]`.

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello"
print "%s %s %s %.2f " %(format_string,data[0],data[1],data[2]
```

This will give you the desired result as:

> Hello John Doe 53.44

Comment: I hope this will solve your problem. Do let em know if it is what you wanted.

Comment: **Exercise**
You will need to write a format string which prints out the data using the following syntax: `Hello John Doe. Your current balance is 53.44$.`

Comment: That can be eaisly done just by putting those words there. Instead of `"%s %s %s %.2f "` you can have `"%s %s %s. Your current balance is %.2f$"`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec), and try something like:

```
>>> data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
>>> format_string = "Hello"
>>> "{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(format_string,*data)  # *data unpacks the content of data
'Hello John Doe 53.44'
```

or:

```
>>> format_string + " {0} {1} {2}".format(*data)
'Hello John Doe 53.44'
```